# Expose std::list member in Python with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, swig

I've been able to use the following typemaps when using a std::list in output or input of a function in C++. These typemaps allow me to use the list object as a standard list in Python.

However, I haven't been able to figure out what typemap to use for a std::list which is a public member of my C++ class.

## MyWork.h

```
class MyWork
{
public:

   // Functions

   void myFunc1(std::list<MyClass> my_list); // OK

   std::list<MyClass> myFunc2(); // OK

   // Properties

   std::list<MyClass> MyList; // ????
};
```

## SWIG Typemaps

```
%typemap(out) std::list<MyClass>
{
PyObject* outList = PyList_New(0);

int error;

std::list<MyClass>::iterator it;
for ( it=$1.begin() ; it != $1.end(); it++ )
{
    PyObject* pyMyClass = SWIG_NewPointerObj(new MyClass(*it), SWIGTYPE_p_MyClass, SWIG_POINTER_OWN );

    error = PyList_Append(outList, pyMyClass);
    Py_DECREF(pyMyClass);
    if (error) SWIG_fail;       
}

$result = outList;
}

%typemap(in) std::list<MyClass>
{
//$input is the PyObject
//$1 is the parameter

if (PyList_Check($input))
{
    std::list<MyClass> listTemp;

    for(int i = 0; i<PyList_Size($input); i++)
    {
        PyObject* pyListItem = PyList_GetItem($input, i);

        MyClass* arg2 = (MyClass*) 0 ;

        int res1 = 0;
        void *argp1;

        res1 = SWIG_ConvertPtr(pyListItem, &argp1, SWIGTYPE_p_MyClass,  0  | 0);
        if (!SWIG_IsOK(res1))
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"List must only contain MyClassobjects");
            return NULL;
        }  
        if (!argp1)
        {
            PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Invalid null reference for object MyClass");
            return NULL;
        }

        arg2 = reinterpret_cast< MyClass* >(argp1);
        listTemp.push_back(*arg2);
    }

    $1 = listTemp;
}
else
{
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,"Wrong argument type, list expected");
    return NULL;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the typemaps provided by SWIG. Add to your SWIG interface file:

```
%include "std_list.i"
%include "MyClass.h" //(or declaration of MyClass)
%template(MyClassList) std::list<MyClass>;
%include "MyWork.h"
```

Done!

---

The answer to your actual question (what typemaps are required to access structure member variables) can be found [here](http://www.swig.org/Doc3.0/SWIGDocumentation.html#SWIGPlus_member_data) in the SWIG documentation:

> The wrapper code to generate the accessors for classes comes from the **pointer** typemaps.

I.e., you need to define

```
%typemap(in) std::list<MyClass> *
%typemap(out) std::list<MyClass> *
```

However, as stated in that same section, it probably makes sense to use the `%naturalvar` directive, and then accessors will use the `const &` typemaps, i.e., you then need to define

```
%typemap(in) const std::list<MyClass> &
%typemap(out) const std::list<MyClass> &
```